# Qt 4.8 beta and Mac OSX Lion, Phonon error

Tags: c++, qt, macos, phonon, osx-lion

After a successful install of mac OS 10.7 I tried to compile my qt 4.7 project.

I had many warnings of "unsupported mac os x version". I thus decided to use Qt 4.8 beta and now, all the warnings are gone.

However, I now have a linker problem using Phonon:

```
dyld: Library not loaded:/Users/pulseagent/repos/build2/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/QtDBus.framework/Versions/4/QtDBus
Referenced from: /Users/kikohs/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/phonon.framework/Versions/Current/phonon
Reason: Incompatible library version: phonon requires version 4.8.0 or later, but QtDBus provides version 4.7.0
```

Do you know I could I fix this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make sure all paths of your development environment point to the new 4.8 version of Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I decided to stick with Qt 4.7.3, to remove the warnings I hacked the qtglobal.h and added Mac 10.7 as a supported version.

It seems to run fine ...

Comment: I don't think so. I only have warnings about deprecated backend cocoa functions (scroll).

Comment: To get qwt (graph framework) compiled, I hacked qtglobal.h as well at ~line 323:                                                     #  if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7)
#       define MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7 MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6 + 1
#  endif
#  if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7)
#    warning "This version of Mac OS X is unsupported"
#  endif

Answer (score 2):

You could easily install QT under Lion using homebrew(which already [has a fix](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/5566) for this):

1. install homebrew using

   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
2. install qt using

   brew install qt --build-from-source

Comment: I would like to stick with the native Qt for mac.

Comment: the installation via homebrew is "native". The only difference is that you build from source

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using MacPorts.  If you download the [MacPorts installer 2.0.0](https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.0.0.tar.gz) (latest at the time of writing) you can unpack the [qt4-mac-devel-4.8.0-beta1.tgz file](https://trac.macports.org/attachment/ticket/30278/qt4-mac-devel-4.8.0-beta1.tgz) posted at the end of this [MacPorts trac report](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30278) over the qt4-mac-devel port, in order to get 4.8.0 beta 1 working under Lion.

It's not official yet, but then nor is Qt 4.8.0.  It seems to work well and can be used to build Qt Creator 2.2.1 without problems.

Comment: Can you deploy as easily as a native Qt for mac app ?

Comment: Yes.  In order to comply with the LGPL license you need to dynamically link with the Qt framework files, include the Qt framework files in the application bundle and modify the binary to use the framework files from within the application bundle.  There are utilities to help do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Qt Creator 2.2.1 and Qt 4.7.4 (64 bit).

While a build in Lion reported a number of warnings (to do with the Mac OS version) the resulting app did work as expected.

Using the macdeployqt tool ( QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/bin/macdeployqt ), with the -dmg switch, creates a dmg file from the app with all of the required dependencies.

And while this reported a number of errors (to do with copying nib files) the resulting dmg file still worked as expected.

Comment: I have the same error nib blabla. To remove the warnings I hacked qtglobal.h to add Lion as a supported version.