# Brew, Lion, Qt 4.8.0

Tags: macos, qt, osx-lion, qt-creator

I've installed qt under Mac OS X Lion with brew through this command:

`brew install qt --build-from-source`.

How could I use Qt now? Has brew installed Qt Creator too? If yes, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't install qt creator afaik.
You might want to get it here: http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools

Comment: That, or just clone it from git and run qmake && make (2.4 branch is probably the best choice)

Comment: I've installed the Qt SDK from here: [link](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/)

Comment: ..Having this problems: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374133/problems-installing-qt-sdk-on-mac-os-x-lion)  than i copied the directory '/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/' in my 'QtSDK 13.05.01/Desktop/Qt/' and from Qt: Preferences Panel->Qt4 i added manually the qMake Location.  It doesn't display any alert but when i run my project i have this problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794005/qt-4-8-beta-and-mac-osx-lion-phonon-error). thanks to bardiir and Frank Osterfiel

Comment: Update: i deleted old build output folders and now it work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the `qt.nokia.com` is gone.
But installers are available for qt 4.8 and 5.3 at http://www.qt.io/download/.